# Run Javascript in Flex Mobile Project

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript, air

From what Ive seen, most of the examples of using Javascript in Flex are designed for for the full desktop version (or for the browser) and not Flex mobile.

For example using **ExternalInterface** in a Flex mobile project gives the error:

```
Error: Error #2067: The ExternalInterface is not available in this container. 
ExternalInterface requires Internet Explorer ActiveX, Firefox, Mozilla 1.7.5 and 
greater, or other browsers that support NPRuntime.
```

**Q.** Is it possible to call Javascript (such as the Google Maps Javascript API) in a Flex mobile project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript functions inside an html (local or remote) loaded by a StageWebView component. Pass whatever argument you want via URL: index.html?param=value.

The ExternalInterface is not supported on mobile profiles.

Comment: Thank you for the information.. finding out what is and isn't supported is really a pain in flex! +1